# d3.csv failed to fetch

Tags: d3.js, typeerror

trying to load csv files using d3.csv, code is here:

```
<html lang = "en">
      <head>
               <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>

              <script>
                      var filename = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/testCSV.csv";
    
                      d3.csv(filename, function(data) {

                      console.log(data);        

                      });

              </script>
      </body>
</html>
```

Local server made by python3, the link and the csv file are working. I am getting the following error:

```
`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
       at mc (d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js:2:100938)
       at <anonymous> (d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js:2:101062)
       at <anonymous> (c:\Users\xxx\test.html:11:12)
       --- Promise.then ---
       at <anonymous> (d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js:2:101070)
       at <anonymous> (c:\Users\xxx\test.html:11:12)
```

`
Please help! Thanks!

I have tried different versions of d3, tried different csv files, and tried putting csv files on google drive and use the link(open restriction) instead of local files. Tried Chrome and Edge. Same error message.